# Intellij IDEA reports 'Cannot assign' every time def is used in Groovy

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

I am struggling to prevent IDEA from complaining about assignment to variable declared by `def` keyword.

[image]

The assignment is absolutely safe as far as I can tell (I observe the same for literals of other types assigned to `def`ed variables). I do not see why assigning `Integer` into `Object` would be a problem in the first place.

There does not seem to be any explanation in inspections settings (Groovy > Assignment issues > Incompatible type assignments) nor any fine grained configuration to tune this. When turned off completely, it stops reporting real problems like `Integer a = ""` as well.

How do I get it to report real problems without highlighting safe assignments?

Comment: Are the groovy libs in a recent version part of the project.  Is this ultimate or free?

Comment: The project has system Groovy SDK configured to the one in the system. But once I configured Java SDK, which was empty by default, the phony messages are gone! Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA can not relay grok the groovy code unless there are both Groovy **and** Java SDKs configured. By importing the project Groovy got configured automatically, but Java did not.

Answer (score 0):

To add, I just ran in to this as well (december 2023) - while starting a new Groovy project using the 'new Project' option in IntellJ community Edition (on Linux). In other words it should have automatically set up everything.

In my case a restart of the IDE fixed the false messages.